# git bash saying a file doesnt exist that does exist?

Tags: windows, bash

git bash is driving me nuts! this is my first time using it so I might be making some new and dumb errors here, I have already looked at a ton of tutorials but something just isn't working. I created a folder on my desktop, my teacher said to type in CD desktop/foldername but when I do that, it says the folder doesn't exist? but it DOES exist? its right on my desktop and i'm staring at it.

Comment: `cd` is used for directories (a.k.a. folders), not files.

Comment: `cd` is for opening directories and not _files_, if you want to open the file on your `desktop`, use text editors like `vi`, e.g. as `vi file`

Comment: This question seems to have little to do with Git and more to do with you being in the wrong folder looking for your file.

Comment: i'm sorry, it is a folder, not a file. my bad let me fix above.

Comment: Run `pwd` and `ls`; what do you see?

Comment: i'm sorry, just `pwd` and `1s` together? (I am unfamiliar with that command -- want to make sure I use the right syntax)
when I type in `pwd 1s` I get `/`

Comment: They're two separate commands. `pwd` prints the current working directory (`/`, evidently), and `ls` (not `1s`) lists the contents of a directory.

Comment: ok `pwd` i get / ... and i'm sorry i see the differnce between `1s` and what you typed but I have never seen that before and i'm not understanding what character is? is that an L? O.o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I'm too low in reputation for putting up comment above. Can you please try this command `cd ~/Desktop/yourfoldername`. I didn't use git bash before but I think this can help if you are running in a bash environment, `find / -name yourfoldername`

Comment: Glad to help you! Have a nice day.